# Do Cuban citizens need transit visa for Canada when flying from the UK to Cuba and back via Canada?

Tags: visas, transit, canada, cuba

As per the title, I'm a Cuban citien with the UK residence card. I would like to travel to Cuba from the UK via Canada and the same on the return journey. My question is: do I need to have transit visa to pass through Canada? I won't be leaving the airport. Thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid you need a eTa even if you don't leave the airport...